# Write to database from R using RODBC:sqlSave not working

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rodbc

I have a SQL database table that I want to populate with data from my R data.frame.  The SQL target table ("SQL_table") already exists in the ODBC SQL database, but is empty of data.  When I try to write my data, it always errors out.  It looks like it's always trying to create the SQL data table?

Here is my code:

```
con <- odbcConnect("SQL_Database", uid="my_user_name", pwd="my_password")
RODBC::sqlSave(channel=con , dat=my_df, tablename = "SQL_table", append=T)
```

Here is the error received:

```
Error in RODBC::sqlSave(channel = con, dat = my_df,  : 
  42S01 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'SQL_table' in the database.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE SQL_table  ("rownames" varchar(255) ..."
```

Troubleshooting thus far:

- I tried running it with append=T & append=F.  Both ways it tries to create the table, making no difference.
- I confirmed that my data schema exactly matches the schema of the target SQL table.
- I confirmed that I can write to the SQL database.
- I tried dropping the database table, and then have R create it from scratch.  Doing so my data will populate then create the table in the SQL database, but not populate it.  In other words, it sends the column names and data types, but not the actual data.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps `SQL_Table` already exists in a schema that's not the user's default schema? Have you tried specifying `SchemaName.TableName` in the `tablename` parameter to be specific about it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by check SchemaName.TableName.  I did go through every column of both tables, confirming that each set of columns is named the same and has the same class of data.

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server every object (stored procedure, table, user-defined function, etc.) exists within a particular schema. Often this defaults to `dbo` but databases can have a plethora of schema names in which objects exist (e.g.: the Northwind example database). I was suggesting that you try including the schema name in your reference so if `SQL_Table` is in the `dbo` schema you'd use `tablename = "dbo.SQL_table"`, or if it were in the `Sales` schema you'd use `tablename = "Sales.SQL_table"`. Users can specify a default schema which may be different than the database's default schema.

Comment: I am using "dbo.My_table" schema, I should have included that in my example code.  R does successfully find that table because I can query data from dbo.My_table.  I've done that with both the empty table and trying when I manually put data in the table via SSMS.